# Finding UUID of a device

Tags: java, android

I am writing an android app for interfacing a Bluetooth Low Energy Pedometer band with Android phone and reading data from it.My app till now successfully scans the pedometer and lists it with its address.
**

```
BAND
FB:02:52:EE:1C:E1
```

**
But i am not having the UUID for the Pedometer. How can i get UUID for the pedometer.If i enters the sample UUID `00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb`

```
`BluetoothGattService mGattService = mBluetoothGatt.getService(UUID);`
```

i get mGattService as null.

Is there any way by which i can get UUID for Pedometer

Comment: AFAIK that you need UUID for the *service running on the pedometer*, not for the individual pedometer itself. This UUID will be the same for all pedometers (or at least all of the same model).

Answer (score 0):

Have a try like;

```
TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String uuid = tManager.getDeviceId();
```

May it will help you.
Thanks!

Comment: what i think is that i am required the service UUId of Pedometer. is there any way by which i can get the UUID of device Bluetooth i.e Pedometer Bluetooth.